# Use checkbox as data binding in vue

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm struggling to find out on how to render the selected values in Vue.

I have a form that runs a query based on the selection:

```
<form id="Register">   
    <br>Firstname<input type="checkbox" value="firstName">
    <br>Lastname<input type="checkbox" value="lastName">
    <br>Nickname<input type="checkbox" value="nickName">
    <br>Mobile<input type="checkbox" value="Mobile"">
    <br><button type="button" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then the queries return a JSON object like this:

```
data: {
    names: [
        { firstName: "Jessica", lastName: "Jones" },
        { firstName: "Mike", lastName: "Lebowski" }
    ]
}
```

But when i try to render this in Vue using v-for

```
<div class v-for="name in names">
    {{name}}
</div>
```

-or-

```
<div class v-for="name in names">
    <div class v-for="details in name"> 
        {{details}}
    </div>
</div>
```

It renders either with the entire object

```
{ firstName: "Jessica", lastname: "Jones" }
```

or with `firstname` on one row and `lastname` on another.

Is there some way you can render everything in one row in the HTML based on the selected input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use destructuring also:

```
<div class v-for="({firstName, lastName}) in names">
  {{firstName}} {{lastName}}
</div>
```

Or, map the properties in line:

```
<div class v-for="name in names">
  {{ Object.keys(name).map(key => name[key]).join(' ') }}
</div>
```

Comment: But if I choose mobile as well as firstname and lastname the data will return with 3 keys.But the data binding only renders 2:  {{firstName}} {{lastName}}

Comment: So add mobile also. You're not restricted to only two properties.

Comment: I think I didn't explain myself good enough. If I make the selection och firstName and lastName and run the query with {{firstName}} {{lastName}} {{mobile}} I will get an error that {{mobile}} is empty. Since the query will only return values that you select the data bindnings can't be fixed. Do you understand?

Comment: Didn't see your edit! That is the answer! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can directly access a property in an object with `objectName.propertyName`.

In your case:

```
<div class v-for="name in names">
    {{name.firstName}} {{name.lastName}}
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I know, but since the property name Will not always be accsesible it doesn’t work. Since I get diffrent data anses on the selection

Comment: You could wrap them in `v-if`then: `<p v-if="name.firstName">{{ name.firstName }}</p>     <p v-if="name.lastName"> {{ name.lastName }}</p>`

Comment: That would require alot of `v-if` statements... Since there will be multiple selections in the final code